# How do I REPLACE values in column after querying

Tags: migration, visual-foxpro

I have a column with numeric values

I am querying

```
SELECT column 
FROM table 
WHERE column='1' OR
column='2' OR 
column='3' OR
column='4'
```

THEN

```
REPLACE (column, "1", "ABC");
REPLACE (column, "2", "DEF");
REPLACE (column, "3", "GHI");
REPLACE (column, "4", "JKL")
```

I am not sure if I may be using the semicolons wrong.

Please help!

Comment: Do you want to update/replace the values in the table? Or just display a modified version and play with string functions?

Comment: Just a display would be better. I dont want to mess with the original database

Answer (score 7):

You can use `CASE` for what you're using the replace for. Also, I've modified the `WHERE` to be more streamlined;

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN column = '1' THEN 'ABC'
    WHEN column = '2' THEN 'DEF'
    WHEN column = '3' THEN 'GHI'
    WHEN column = '4' THEN 'JKL'
END AS column
FROM table
WHERE column IN ('1','2','3','4')
```

As a note, if `column` is an `int` then you don't need to wrap the values in ''

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN column = 1 THEN 'ABC'
    WHEN column = 2 THEN 'DEF'
    WHEN column = 3 THEN 'GHI'
    WHEN column = 4 THEN 'JKL'
END AS column
FROM table
WHERE column IN (1,2,3,4)
```

This won't modify the table at all, it will just change the way that the data is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use:

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN column = 1 THEN 'ABC'
  WHEN column = 2 THEN 'DEF'
  WHEN column = 3 THEN 'GHI'
END AS column
FROM table
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

By using REPLACE alone, you can use like the below:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column, '1', 'ABC'), '2', 'DEF'), '3', 'GHI'), '4', 'JKL')
FROM table 
WHERE column IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')
```

The replace should be nested on other, not separate by semi colon.
More over in `WHERE` clause instead of the `OR` you can use `IN`